# Sign in using Twitter for users that already have accounts

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I have a website where users already have accounts (email/password).  I'd like to add sign-in with Twitter and Facebook to the login page.  How do you go about linking accounts?  Say a user is already signed up and now they want to sign in using Twitter.  How do you verify their account and their twitter account match? I'd prefer not to have users have multiple accounts (one for email/password, one for twitter, one for facebook), but allow them to use any option to sign in.

I'm aware of https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-in-with-twitter. It more of an understanding of preventing duplicate accounts or linking accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Provide users who are authorized a way to link their account to a twitter account e.g. in their profile page. Users who want to switch to twitter auth will know that they have to somehow mark their account for that instead of re-registering, so they will probably look in their profile/account page.